# Why using %s for character variable donot execute statements below it in c?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=2;

    char ch='c';

    printf("%i\n",x);
    printf("%s\n",ch);
    printf("Hello");

    return 0;

}
```

In this code snippet, I accidently put %s for printing the value of ch rather than using %c, but I found that It does not print "Hello". So far, I know, %s accepts a char pointer and it does look for a null character to terminate, but can you explain what is happening here? I am beginner and eager to know about this.

Comment: The program crashes ("segmentation fault"), because it tries to dereference the ascii value of `c` as a memory address, which for sure isn't mapped.

Comment: One way to catch this sort of bug in the future would be to compile your code with warnings. For example, with the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags.

Comment: because ch is a character, not a string

Comment: Save time. Enable all  warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Using an incorrect conversion specifier in `printf` results in undefined behavior.

You declared the variable `ch` as having the type `char`.

```
char ch='c';
```

But the conversion specifier `%s` expects  an argument of the type `char *` that shall point to a (null terminated) string. Thus the value of `ch` 'c' is `interpreted` as a memory address.

```
printf("%s\n",ch);
```

Instead use

```
printf("%c\n",ch);
```

Otherwise declare the variable `ch` like

```
char *ch = "c";
```

and then

```
printf("%s\n",ch);
```